# R raster plot produces small/barely visible grid cells with large gaps in between

Tags: raster, r, plot

I have a dataset with lat/lon coordinates. I've converted the dataset in R to a raster layer using raster::rasterFromXYZ (Raster package). The dimensions of the raster layer are: 1249, 2551, 3186199 (nrow, ncol, ncell). I've checked the spatial extent and everything looks fine: -83.13167, -74.62833, 41.70833, 45.87167 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax); the data covers Southern Ontario, Canada.

I've used the rasterFromXYZ function for other locations and datasets and it works fine, for example, the last figure below (Vancouver, Canada), but when I use it on the dataset (df) below (a subset of the full dataset described above) the grids are tiny, nearly visible and large space between them (figures below). The resolutions are the same: 0.003333333, 0.003333333 (x, y), for both of the figures.

Do raster layers have maximum ncells they can handle? Or is there a way to increase the grid cell size?

```
df <- structure(list(lon = c(-82.71, -82.63, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                             -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, 
                             -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, 
                             -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                             -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, 
                             -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, 
                             -81.96, -81.88, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                             -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, 
                             -81.79, -82.96, -82.88, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, 
                             -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                             -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, 
                             -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, 
                             -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, 
                             -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, 
                             -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, 
                             -81.46, -81.38, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, 
                             -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, 
                             -81.38, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, 
                             -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -82.46, 
                             -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, 
                             -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, 
                             -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, 
                             -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, 
                             -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, 
                             -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, 
                             -80.29, -80.21, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, 
                             -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -81.29, 
                             -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, 
                             -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, -79.96, 
                             -79.88, -79.79, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, 
                             -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, 
                             -80.13, -80.04, -79.96, -79.88, -79.79, -79.71, -79.63, -79.54, 
                             -79.46, -79.38, -79.29, -79.21, -79.13, -79.04, -78.96, -78.88, 
                             -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, 
                             -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, 
                             -79.96, -79.88, -79.79, -79.71, -79.63, -79.54, -79.46, -79.38, 
                             -79.29, -79.21, -79.13, -79.04, -78.96, -78.88), lat = c(41.71, 
                                                                                      41.71, 41.79, 41.79, 41.79, 41.87, 41.87, 41.87, 41.87, 41.96, 
                                                                                      41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 
                                                                                      42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 
                                                                                      42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 
                                                                                      42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 
                                                                                      42.21, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 
                                                                                      42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.37, 42.37, 
                                                                                      42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 
                                                                                      42.37, 42.37, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 
                                                                                      42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                      42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                      42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                      42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                      42.62, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 
                                                                                      42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                      42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                      42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                      42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                      42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                      42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                      42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 
                                                                                      42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                      42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                      42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                      42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                      42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                      42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                      42.96, 42.96), hist_sum = c(203, 203.5, 192, 197, 194.5, 186, 
                                                                                                                  185.5, 189, 189, 188.5, 187.5, 187, 186.5, 186.5, 186.5, 185.5, 
                                                                                                                  195, 196.5, 190, 190.5, 187.5, 182, 178, 182.5, 183.5, 183.5, 
                                                                                                                  182.5, 178.5, 173, 169.5, 172.5, 172, 169.5, 188.5, 184.5, 184.5, 
                                                                                                                  182, 174, 171.5, 169, 165.5, 165.5, 171.5, 171.5, 170.5, 173.5, 
                                                                                                                  176, 192, 187.5, 179.5, 174, 170, 166, 164, 164.5, 169, 171.5, 
                                                                                                                  173, 171, 171, 173.5, 174.5, 177, 176, 165, 165, 165, 172, 178.5, 
                                                                                                                  175.5, 175.5, 179.5, 178, 178, 178.5, 157, 157.5, 160, 165.5, 
                                                                                                                  166, 171, 173, 178, 179, 179, 179.5, 186, 187, 145, 154.5, 156.5, 
                                                                                                                  159, 163, 164, 166.5, 167, 166, 167, 172, 181.5, 186.5, 189.5, 
                                                                                                                  190, 190, 145.5, 159, 160.5, 161, 164.5, 165, 165, 164.5, 167.5, 
                                                                                                                  169.5, 175.5, 177.5, 181.5, 188, 188.5, 133, 150, 154, 156, 159, 
                                                                                                                  160, 161, 161.5, 165, 168.5, 169.5, 172.5, 177, 186, 188.5, 146.5, 
                                                                                                                  152, 154, 158.5, 159, 160.5, 161, 163, 164.5, 167, 170, 174.5, 
                                                                                                                  178, 181.5, 142, 148, 154.5, 158.5, 166.5, 163, 159.5, 162.5, 
                                                                                                                  162, 165, 168.5, 170.5, 172, 182, 142, 154, 159.5, 160.5, 161.5, 
                                                                                                                  157, 155, 161.5, 163.5, 168.5, 171.5, 174.5, 176.5, 181, 182, 
                                                                                                                  184, 186, 185.5, 185, 183, 180.5, 183, 181.5, 192.5, 199.5, 198, 
                                                                                                                  197.5, 192.5, 189, 187.5, 187, 192, 193.5, 195.5, 194, 188, 188.5, 
                                                                                                                  197.5, 201.5, 204, 201.5, 200.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 194.5, 
                                                                                                                  196.5, 204.5, 197.5, 193.5, 192.5, 200.5, 199, 198, 200.5, 206, 
                                                                                                                  203.5, 204.5, 201.5, 197.5, 194, 196.5, 197, 193, 186.5, 187, 
                                                                                                                  179.5, 175.5, 170.5, 185.5, 187.5, 188.5, 192, 198.5, 209, 210, 
                                                                                                                  206.5, 205.5, 205, 197, 191, 193.5, 188.5, 183.5, 184, 181.5, 
                                                                                                                  174, 167.5, 166, 168, 167.5, 169.5, 175, 179.5, 180.5, 178.5, 
                                                                                                                  183.5, 187, 172, 184, 181, 185, 187, 190, 194, 198.5, 198.5, 
                                                                                                                  197, 192.5, 192, 185, 182.5, 178, 174.5, 176.5, 167.5, 165.5, 
                                                                                                                  162.5, 161, 163, 164.5, 163.5, 170.5, 179, 180, 179, 180, 176.5, 
                                                                                                                  164)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -291L))
```

```
library(raster)

canada_map <- getData("GADM",country="can",level=1)
raster <- rasterFromXYZ(df[,c(1,2,3)])
raster
col_ramp <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "red"))
cuts_year <- pretty(df[,3], n = 20)
cuts_averages <- pretty(df[,3], n = 20)

plot(df$lon, df$lat)

plot(raster$hist_sum, breaks = cuts_year, col = col_ramp(25))
# plot(canada_map[9,], add = TRUE)
mtext("Longitude", side = 1, line = 2.1, font = 2, cex = 1)
mtext("Latitude", side = 2, line = 2.6, font = 2, cex = 1)
# abline(v = pretty(df[,1], n = 10), lty = 3, lwd = 0.2, col = "grey75")
# abline(h = pretty(df[,2], n = 10), lty = 3, lwd = 0.2, col = "grey75")
```

Plot output from code above:
[image]
Zoomed into the middle left, you see the small size of the grid cells and large gaps between the individual grid cells.
[image]
I used the exact same method/code on another dataset, although with smaller dimensions: 14, 47, 658 (nrow, ncol, ncell), and it worked out fine.
[image]

Comment: Pixels in degrees are of different area by latitude.

Comment: @Vince, sorry, what does that mean? Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: By that I mean perceived size may change depending on location and display projection. You can see it in your graphics, where height != width.